# How to convert data from ASCII to Unicode (correct collation)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, ssis, ascii

Hi I have problem that I'm dealing first time. I have MS SQL Server Databse with collation `Latin1_General_CS_AS` (code 1252). But there data is actually in Lithuanian language 'Lithuanian_CS_AS' (code 1257). I need to get data and write in another database, converted in 'normal' strings - probably unicode. I'm using also SSIS if this can help resolve problem.

**Data**:

`B×kÑiÖ g. 11-12`:

```
   print ASCII(SUBSTRING(@string, @position, 1)) 
   print CHAR(ASCII(SUBSTRING(@string, @position, 1)))

66  B | 215 × | 107 k | 209 Ñ | 105 i | 214 Ö | 32  | 103 g | 46  . | 32  | 49  1 | 49  1 | 45  - | 49  1 | 50  2
```

Using  this ASCII page of codes http://www.ascii-codes.com/cp775.html it must be converted to:

**Result**:

```
Būkčių g. 11-12
```

Maybe there are sql query which can convert `B×kÑiÖ g. 11-12 --> Būkčių g. 11-12` ?

Some [**SQLFIDDLESampleData**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/80aec/1) if you can convert this in Lithuanian Language. I would like to solve this easy, without converting each character in 'Lithuanian' language because this would be insane :)

**More Info**

Database with collation `Latin1_General_CS_AS` users using with software (reports, forms), where  everything is ok in Lithuanian language (I don't know how they can see correct letters). I'm using MS SQL Server 2008 r2.

I can be not always near computer, but I try to answer all your questions. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have come to a decision use functions: [REPLACE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) [CHAR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187323%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

In my case `varchar` was datatype for columns. So to convert to proper language words in unicode (`nvarchar`) steps:

1. Convert the column in unicode with `CS` and `AS` atributtes in select statement:

`SELECT cast(column Collate Latin1_General_CS_AS as nvarchar(22))`

2.And use replace statement to convert in real letters code::

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(cast(column Collate Latin1_General_CS_AS as nvarchar(22)),CHAR(181),N'Ą'), CHAR(208), N'ą'),CHAR(182),N'Č'), CHAR(209), N'č'), CHAR(183), N'Ę'), CHAR(210), N'ę'),CHAR(184), N'Ė'), CHAR(211), N'ė'),CHAR(189), N'Į'),CHAR(212), N'į'), CHAR(190), N'Š'), CHAR(213), N'š'), CHAR(198), N'Ų'), CHAR(214), N'ų'),CHAR(199), N'Ū'), CHAR(215), N'ū'), CHAR(207), N'Ž'), CHAR(216), N'ž')
```

Result:

```
|       ¾ilutÓs pl. 83 |       Šilutės pl. 83 |
|         B×kÑiÖ g. 11 |         Būkčių g. 11 |
|          Seni×kÖ km. |          Seniūkų km. |
```

Answer (score 3):

How about the [COLLATE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184391.aspx) clause?

From MSDN:

Specifying collation during a select

The following example creates a simple table and inserts 4 rows. Then the example applies two collations when selecting data from the table, demonstrating how Chiapas is sorted differently.

```
CREATE TABLE Locations
(Place varchar(15) NOT NULL);
GO
INSERT Locations(Place) VALUES ('Chiapas'),('Colima')
                         , ('Cinco Rios'), ('California');
GO
--Apply an typical collation
SELECT Place FROM Locations
ORDER BY Place
COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS_KS_WS ASC;
GO
-- Apply a Spanish collation
SELECT Place FROM Locations
ORDER BY Place
COLLATE Traditional_Spanish_ci_ai ASC;
GO
```

Comment: Sorry this is not that I'm looking for, It not works with my data. There are the same unrecognizable characters.

Comment: Ok, you may want to spend a few minutes reading up on collation and encoding though (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143726.aspx) as it seems like you're confusing ASCII and Unicode at the target.   Alternatively, maybe look at using nvarchar instead for your column?